# UIImageView change with beacons

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiimageview, ibeacon

I am trying to change a single `UIImageView` on a view controller screen with the following code. But it is currently, not working.. Can someone point me towards the right direction?

```
var imageView = UIImageView()

let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
let region = CLBeaconRegion(proximityUUID: UUID(uuidString: "B9407F30-F5F8-466E-AFF9-25556B57FE6D")!, identifier: "Estimotes")

let images = [
    53219:  UIImage(named:"White Glyph 2"),
    59317:  UIImage(named:"White Glyph 3"),
    17068: UIImage(named:"White Glyph 4")
]


func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didRangeBeacons beacons: [CLBeacon], in region: CLBeaconRegion) {
    let knownBeacons = beacons.filter{ $0.proximity != CLProximity.unknown }
    if (knownBeacons.count > 0) {
        let closestBeacon = knownBeacons[0] as CLBeacon
        self.imageView.image = self.images[closestBeacon.minor.intValue]!
    }
}
```

Comment: When running your app, did you got the location permission request?
If not, you maybe need to add `Privacy - Location Always Usage Description` to your .plist file

Comment: What is not working? Do you find at least beacons? Is `didRangeBeacons` called? Where did you initialized you `locationManager`? Did you set its delegate?

Comment: Did you add your UIImageView to your ViewController.View?

Comment: @Larme locationManager is initialized by code that is not posted. Everything related to beacon connectivity is working. what is not working is changing the set imageView to a different image when the "closestBeacon.minor.intValue" changes.

Comment: @ReinierMelian Yes I did

Comment: @Rags93 Thank you for that reminder! I did set that in the .plist already though.

Comment: Quick question Is `self.images[closestBeacon.minor.intValue]` correct? And also, are you in main thread when `didRangeBeacons:` is called?

Comment: The UIImageView needed an outlet from the storyboard. That was the fix, thank you all.